# Logback 1.2.11 leaving large amount of .tmp files on a multithreaded application in kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, multithreading, logback, rollback

I have created a logback-spring.xml file for a application that is multithreaded and is running in kubernetes. I am using a SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy and it leaves a large amount of .tmp files. I have cross verified with the logback configurations and everything seems to be alright.

Logback-spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" name="STDOUT">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <timestamp key="timestamp" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <property resource="application.yml"/>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${logging.path}/log_${timestamp}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class = "ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${logging.path}/archive/log_%d{yyyy-MM-  dd}_%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <maxFileSize>15MB</maxFileSize>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

The archive folder in kubernetes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NYWj.png)

Please provide help on how to solve this issue. Thanks!!